# Are there any good patterns/principles for separating out Create and Update logic

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dns, crud

Taking the simple example of a user, in my experience, I have found that there is always a slightly different piece of checking/logic to perform depending on whether you are creating or updating a user (this problem extends to updating other domain entities too).  The code quickly gets spaghetti-fied when you add liberal sprinkilings with rationale such as
 "Just do this check for the user when updating them" and "ooh just do this check, logic, insert when creating the user"

The sum of all this is a monolithic behemoth of code  which is a bloody eyesore to look at. I suppose its just common-sense to refactor/separate out this logic completely. Or am I mad.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Template Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx) for this situation.  Basically, you can put all the duplicate code in the base class and have the inherited classes implement the specifics.  A simple psuedo code example would look like this:

IRep

```
class IRep
{
   void Add(object a);
   void Remove(object a);
}
```

BaseRep

```
abstract class BaseRep : IRep
{
    void Add(object a)
    {
       if(OkToAdd(a))
       {
          // Common Rep code here
       }
    }

    void Remove(object a)
    {
       if(OkToRemove(b))
       {
          // Common Rep code here
       }
    }

    abstract bool OkToAdd(object a);
    abstract bool OkToRemove(object a);
}
```

MyRep1

```
class MyRep1 : BaseRep
{
    bool OkToAdd(object a)
    {
       // Add specific checks here for MyRep1
    }

    bool OkToRemove(object a)
    {
       // Add specific checks here for MyRep1
    }
}
```

MyRep2

```
class MyRep2 : BaseRep
{
    bool OkToAdd(object a)
    {
       // Add specific checks here for MyRep2
    }

    bool OkToRemove(object a)
    {
       // Add specific checks here for MyRep2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. This is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there basically is two patterns to choose from:

1. Make completely separate cases for adding and updating.
2. Make a single case that handles both adding and updating.

The advantage of having separate cases is that the code gets cleaner, the drawback is that you are repeating most of the code. Using a single case to avoid repeating the code also means that the code gets more complex.

Trying to create something that is in-between will most likely end up with the drawbacks of both patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have them completely separated. Even though this may look as code duplication, it allows to evolve these actions independently in the future. And they can get quite different from each other: when creating, there may be some fields not required, or even not allowed to be set, and there may be lots of different rules to be checked in each case. If you completely separate these actions, then you have complete freedom how to evolve them.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found that there is always a
>   slightly different piece of
>   checking/logic to perform depending on
>   whether you are creating or updating a
>   user

*Of course* there is different logic involved.

Creating an entity and making a change to an entity are two distinctly different operations.  Don't try to make them the same operation.

Comment: I agreee, the domain entity almost always remains the same, the operations performed on it or with it, differ.  It is apparent to me and  obvious, as you pointed out. The intent of my question was to garner, for certain, whether or not I should ensure that these operations aren't too intermindlged. That is to separate them out.

Comment: And I am saying, separate them out. Furthermore, having just simply an "Update" is also *far* to general in most cases.  Update what and why?  In the case of a user you may be changing their username or their email or their password - all of which are likely to have very different requirements and therefore should not be a single "Update" function (that could presumably change any of the data).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm a few years further on in my career and I now have an awareness of a number of approaches when designing/understanding software.

It seems what I was describing seems symptomatic of an anaemic domain model and transaction script.  Where the business rules buried in the method/operation used for  persistance quickly becomes tangled if shoe-horned into a create/upsert/update operation on a repository or against a persistence store.

Intent and business rules are quickly lost in this kind of approach.

A way to alleviate this is to lean on a DDD approach and carefully model behaviour so that only relevant state is changed and then persisted (most likely on an aggregate or entity/value object in that aggregate).  This helps ensure that there is an auditable story by virtue of an operation explicitly indicating what state is being changed.  For example:

```
Customer.AddUsername(string username)
```

Where this method would update the username, with scope to have business rules in play within the operation.